# How to show all items in Vuetify Data Table instead of 10 rows only?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using a [data table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#data-tables) from Vuetify:

```
<v-data-table
  :ref="`sortableTable${index}`"
  class="items-table-container"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="category.items"
  hide-default-footer>

    ...custom rows

</v-data-table>
```

I noticed that when adding a new item to the table, it wasn't appearing. I verified that the items I'm passing it have 11 items, however the table is only displaying 10 max.

When I looked at the wrapper surrounding the table, I noticed that it had:

```
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

however, I'm unable to override it for some reason. I've tried adding the `height` prop but nothing seems to work.

How can I give the table an auto height, so that it expands no matter how many rows are in the table?

Comment: One can set the default to "All" by the value "-1".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This issue is happening because you have removed default footer using `hide-default-footer`, but the pagination is still enabled. Pagination is by default set to show only 10 items per row. You can easily fix this by simply adding `disable-pagination` options, which disables pagination completely and then you can see all items after 10th index also.

```
<v-data-table
  :ref="`sortableTable${index}`"
  class="items-table-container"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="category.items"
  hide-default-footer
  disable-pagination>
```

**DEMO:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{text:"Dessert (100g serving)",align:"start",sortable:!1,value:"name"},{text:"Calories",value:"calories"},{text:"Fat (g)",value:"fat"},{text:"Carbs (g)",value:"carbs"},{text:"Protein (g)",value:"protein"},{text:"Iron (%)",value:"iron"}],
      desserts: headers=[{name:"Frozen Yogurt",calories:159,fat:6,carbs:24,protein:4,iron:"1%"},{name:"Ice cream sandwich",calories:237,fat:9,carbs:37,protein:4.3,iron:"1%"},{name:"Eclair",calories:262,fat:16,carbs:23,protein:6,iron:"7%"},{name:"Cupcake",calories:305,fat:3.7,carbs:67,protein:4.3,iron:"8%"},{name:"Gingerbread",calories:356,fat:16,carbs:49,protein:3.9,iron:"16%"},{name:"Jelly bean",calories:375,fat:0,carbs:94,protein:0,iron:"0%"},{name:"Lollipop",calories:392,fat:.2,carbs:98,protein:0,iron:"2%"},{name:"Honeycomb",calories:408,fat:3.2,carbs:87,protein:6.5,iron:"45%"},{name:"Donut",calories:452,fat:25,carbs:51,protein:4.9,iron:"22%"},{name:"KitKat",calories:518,fat:26,carbs:65,protein:7,iron:"6%"},{name:"Jelly bean",calories:375,fat:0,carbs:94,protein:0,iron:"0%"},{name:"Lollipop",calories:392,fat:.2,carbs:98,protein:0,iron:"2%"},
{name:"Ice cream sandwich",calories:237,fat:9,carbs:37,protein:4.3,iron:"1%"},{name:"Eclair",calories:262,fat:16,carbs:23,protein:6,iron:"7%"},{name:"Cupcake",calories:305,fat:3.7,carbs:67,protein:4.3,iron:"8%"},
{name:"Ice cream sandwich",calories:237,fat:9,carbs:37,protein:4.3,iron:"1%"},{name:"Eclair",calories:262,fat:16,carbs:23,protein:6,iron:"7%"},{name:"Cupcake",calories:305,fat:3.7,carbs:67,protein:4.3,iron:"8%"}],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout column>
        <v-data-table :headers="headers" 
          :items="desserts" 
          class="elevation-1" 
          hide-default-footer 
          disable-pagination
          dense>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: One would think that `hide-default-footer` will automatically turns `pagination` `off`. My god, why would I want it to be `on` if I turned the footer `off` , this is crazy ... Anyway thank you 

Comment: @AdamOrłowski because one might be using a custom footer.

Comment: @andreyrk I think you misunderstood.

Comment: @AdamOrłowski care to explain how so? custom footers can still use the pagination features and they can be actioned through the API, they aren't mutually inclusive features so there's no reason why pagination would should be turned off automatically if you turn off footers

Comment: @andreyrk because when I turned off the footer, pagination disappeared. So I assumed that pagination is off and was wondering why there are only 10 rows. It is misleading.

Comment: @AdamOrłowski honestly I don't quite get it, the footer only displays some information about the pagination, and one would normally want to restyle and show these info in different ways when using a custom footer. But I agree it can be confusing so it'd be good if folks at Vuetify clarified on the documentation

Comment: I can't disable it - or I can but it only shows the first 100 items of my 1500 results ?

Comment: I should add I can get pagination to show but it just doesn't work and always shows 100.

Answer (score 4):

The default item count per page is 10. use -1 instead of 10. add this line.

```
:items-per-page="-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add  `disable-pagination`  in your v-data-table tag and it should look something like this

`<v-data-table \*more items come in here *\ disable-pagination>`

then Vuetify DataTable will render out all the data in one continual table.